# Fixed Header getting cuttoff on Mobile Browser

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header for mobile that has the css:

```
header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 40%;
height: 70px;
background: #191919;
z-index: 10;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

This works fine in most browsers but in the Samsung Browser is gets cut or is hidden by the status bar as per the image below especially on scroll

[image: Mobile Header Capture]

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #191919;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<header class="myheader">My Header</header>

<div class="content">Some content</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a meta-viewport tag in place? - and if so, what is it?

Comment: Yes. It is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Hi try meta-"viewport" -  @user38208 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: @PiyushTeraiya this doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple solution. I added overflow: scroll to `#main { overflow: scroll;}`, the div container holding the header and the content below and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You might get punished by “The Notch”-feature of newer mobile devices

Please try to set `viewport-fit=cover`

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Further properties to handle any adjustment:

- safe-area-inset-top
- safe-area-inset-right
- safe-area-inset-left
- safe-area-inset-bottom

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/the-notch-and-css/